# How to Focus TextInput in React Native Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created `floatingLabelInputFocus.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native';
export default class FloatingLabelInputFocus extends Component {
    state = {
        isFocused: false,
    };

    handleFocus = () => this.setState({ isFocused: true });
    handleBlur = () => this.setState({ isFocused: false });

    render() {
        const { label, ...props } = this.props;
        const { isFocused } = this.state;
        const labelStyle = {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: (!isFocused&&props.value==="") ? 5 : 0,
            fontSize: !isFocused ? 25 : 20,
            color: !isFocused ? '#aaa' : '#000',
        };
        return (
            <View style={{ paddingTop: 10}}>
                <Text style={labelStyle}>
                    {label}
                </Text>
                <TextInput
                    ref={(r) => this.props.onRef(r)}
                    {...props}
                    style={{ height: 50, fontSize: 25, color: '#000', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: '#555', marginTop:25 }}
                    onFocus={this.handleFocus}
                    onBlur={this.handleBlur}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And I am using is as

```
  <FloatingLabelInputFocus
                    onRef={(r) => this.myField2 = r}
                    label="SKID CODE"
                    value={this.state.itemCode}
                    onKeyMultipleListener={() => alert('Keyboard Hidden')}
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ itemCode: text })}
                />
```

I have the reference of TextInput as `this.myField2`. 
 However, when I do `this.myField2.focus()` in `componentDidMount(){this.myField2.focus()}` It doesn't work.
What is the correct way to focus TextInput?

**UPDATE:**

I found the issue is with when I go to the next page and come back the focus is not working. At this time the componentDidMount() , render(), componentDidUpdate() methods are not called. 

`navigate('ProcessItem', { user });`

in `'ProcessSkid'` and from `'ProcessItem'` I am doing

```
const navigate = navigation.navigate; 
const user = navigation.getParam('user', {}); 
navigate('ProcessSkid', { user });
```

At this time the TextInput is not focused.

Comment: I tried this in a snack and it works fine and focus the texinput

Comment: I found the issue is with when I do  navigate('ProcessItem', {
                                                    user
                                                });  in 'ProcessSkid' and from 'ProcessItem' I am doing  const navigate = navigation.navigate;
                          const user = navigation.getParam('user', {});
                          navigate('ProcessSkid', { user });
At this time the TextInput is not focused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you navigate to another component react-navigation doesn't unmount the component you were on, that's why it doesn't call `componentDidMount`.

Theres many ways to solve this

Add listeners:

```
<NavigationEvents
  onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
  onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)} // 
  onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
  onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
/>
```

**OR**

```
this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload=>{console.log(payload)})
```

And if you're using `react-navigation` V5 you can use [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#unmountonblur).